# Cannot add a photo to an album in Camera Roll

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app, camera, album

In the Photos app on my iPhone 4 with iOS 5, I cannot add a photo in the Camera Roll to another album. The album is there, but I cannot select it after tapping on the "Add to" button.
The album I am trying to copy the photo is an iPhoto album synced to the phone.   Can this be the reason of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked and answered. The iOS 5 Photo app allows you add photos from the camera roll to the albums you create on the device, but not to albums created on the Mac using iPhoto or Aperture.

When those photos are [downloaded](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4083) to the computer (manually or by [Photostream](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486)) you can remove them from the device, which removes them from the device-created album, and add them to the appropriate album in iPhoto. They'll be added to the iPhoto album on the device the next time the device is [synced with iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4236).